# Unable to login to the jboss 7.1 admin console on windows

Tags: jboss7.x

Unable to login to the jboss 7.1 and 7.1.1 admin console on windows  Server 2008 HPC Edition. i try also to add a new user(add-user.bat) nothing. Even the default user: admin=admin doesn't work.

This problem happens on domain and standalone.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

With `add-user.bat`:

```
Realm (ManagementRealm) : ManagementRealm
Username : q
Password : superpassword
Re-enter Password : superpassword
```

The problem was that the  *Realm (ManagementRealm)* value must be the same: `ManagementRealm`

Comment: Thanks , mistake i was making was , choosing my own "Realm" :D

Comment: can u explain more ?

Answer (score 18):

There is a better solution if you don't want to add a second user that you might forget the password for again.

Folow these steps:

1. open `jboss-as-x.x.x.Final\standalone\configuration\mgmt-users.properties` and delete the user (i.e delete the line which has the username you want to use, such as `admin=2c7123264278731425d1f53aeb55da1e`)
2. open `jboss-as-x.x.x.Final\domain\configuration\mgmt-users.properties` and delete the user (i.e delete the line which has the username you want to use, such as `admin=2c7123264278731425d1f53aeb55da1e`)
3. run `jboss-as-x.x.x.Final\bin\add-user.bat` and add user in the following way:

   3.1 select user type `a`

   3.2 Realm (ManagementRealm) : `ManagementRealm`

   3.3 Username : `admin`

   3.4 Password : `password`

   3.5 Re-enter Password : `password`

If you get `JBAS015243: The user ‘admin’ already exists in at least one properties file.` error, then you didn't complete steps 1 and 2.